# How did this question get closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

I happened to come across [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361773/using-the-correct-word) question that was put on hold as being opinion-based:

> Is someone who favours someone from their own country -regardless of the other persons colour- still classed as *racist*?

I'd like to know how this came about, as I think it leads in a single, well-defined direction.

Comment: Hey, since you're mostly asking about a specific question, I changed your title to match. If you really want to ask the more general question, please feel free to rollback, but I'd also recommend you add more details and additional examples to the body of your question.

Comment: I'm confused why you don't seem to have voted to re-open, give your view.

Comment: @aparente001, as I was really confused about the _reason_ it was put on hold I decided to seek feedback. No sense in entering some leapfrog back-and-forth because I'm in the dark about some convention? That, and plain curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying the [principle of charity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_charity), I personally read this question to be about the definition of the term *racist*. Does the term *racist* include prejudice that is based on country of origin? This is a request for a "correct" answer. Because of that, I agree with you. I wouldn't personally flag it as opinion-based.

However, the question is so short that it's hard to know what the asker really wants. I can understand how reasonable people might flag it as a request for opinion. In any case, we're in the dark about what the asker has already considered and why there is still a question. I'd actually flag it to be closed as either unclear or lacks research.

Comment: Some questions more than others challenge to provide clarity of thought and proper use of definitions. IMHO especially those who  query the darker side of the human mind, like this one. That is why I strive to keep them available for others to come, quite separate from technical question quality. Life never is that clear-cut after all.